# Display Facebook wall posts using the Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm having trouble using **FB.Facebook.apiClient.stream_get** (as in, I don't know how it works), but I have not been able to find clear instructions on how to use it to get all the posts made on the Wall of my fan page. Can someone provide me with some instruction?

Thanks, much appreciated!

Tom Nchinda

Answer (score 2):

I highly advise you to use the new [Open Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api).

You can call the API using the new Javascript SDK like this : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api